# Django using MinLengthValidator removes zero in begin of text

Tags: django

i want to validate national_code, it is exactly 10 digit and maybe starts with zero, like 0********* or 00********, so i wrote in my model:

```
national_code = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
```

but when storing 0012345678, it raises error telling length should be 10 and it is 8! why?

Comment: It means that by the time the number is getting to the model for saving, the preceding two zeros have been stripped and the remaining characters are 8 in number. You might need to probably check what is being sent to the database and make sure it's a string

Comment: of course i checked it, what finally is stored, is string, containing zero at begin of text, but `MinLengthValidator` has different behavior. data is sent via simple `ModelForm`